# How to Assign user to public group based on profile

Tags: public-group

How to create public Group based on the profiles

Requirement:
I have certain profiles 
For ex:

```
   Profile 1
   profile 2
   profile 3
   profile 4
```

How to add these profiles related user to the public group .

Instead of trigger,can I use anonymous window?

Comment: this question becomes notable question, but I got down Vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code works for me

```
   list<groupMember> groupList = new list<groupMember>();
   Group grp = [select id from Group where DeveloperName='new_public_Group']; 
     List<user> userList=[select id,profileId from User where profileId IN ('00e1g000000HhnW','00eE0000000j8T0','00eE00000015tVE','00eE00000015tVF','00eE00000015tVG','00eE00000015tVI','00eE00000015tVJ','00eE00000015tVH','00eE0000000mva9') and IsActive=true];

  for(user u:userList){ 
  groupMember gp = new groupMember(); 
  gp.groupId = grp.Id; gp.UserOrGroupId = u.Id; groupList.add(gp); 
   } 
   if (groupList.size()>0)  
   database.Insert(groupList,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Members of a Public Group can be either - (other) Public Group, Roles, Roles & Sub Ordinates or Users.

I see the following possibilities for adding the related users to the Public Group:

- If your profiles are sharing specific roles then you can add those to the public group
- Add the users of each of these profiles to the Public Group.

More helpful information

- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=user_groups_considerations.htm&type=5
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/users_group_member_types.htm

Let me know if you need more help in solving the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid I believe this is not possible without the use of an Apex Trigger.

The trigger would fire on the user object and add the record to a public group when the profile equals your examples.

There is an idea to upvote as well: [Allow public groups to reference profiles](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KPyAAAW)

Edit, I found this previous question that may help if you go down the trigger route.[trigger to add active user with standard profile to public group](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/108818/trigger-to-add-active-user-with-standard-profile-to-public-group)